# imacros - dropdown select code not functioning

Tags: html, firefox, select, drop-down-menu, imacros

I have a code to select an option from a dropdown box which seems to work on one page of a website, but does not function on the other.

The code that works looks like this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:quickOutputTemplate ATTR=NAME:saveToMenu CONTENT=$Save<SP>to<SP>Other<SP>File<SP>Formats
```

for this html:

```
<script type="text/template" id="quickOutputTemplate">            <input type="hidden" value="other" name="selectedQOFormat" /> <select class="saveToMenu" id="saveToMenu" name="saveToMenu" onchange="saveOutputForm('UA_output_input_form'); return false;">  <option  value="enw"><a href="#" class="quickOutputENW">Save to EndNote online</a></option>   <option  value="endnote"><a href="#" class="quickOutputEndNote">Save to EndNote desktop</a></option>    <option  value="rid"><a href="#" class="quickOutputRID">Save to ResearcherID - I wrote these</a></option>    <option selected="selected" value="other"><a href="#" class="quickOutputOther">Save to Other File Formats</a></option>  </select>  </script>
```

However when I try to use the same format:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:cr_quickOutputTemplate ATTR=ID:cr_saveToMenu CONTENT=$Save<SP>to<SP>Text<SP>File
```

It does not work for this html:

```
<script type="text/template" id="cr_quickOutputTemplate">   <select class="saveToMenu" id="cr_saveToMenu"> <option selected="selected" value="other"><a href="#" class="cr_quickOutputOther">Save to Text File</a></option> <option  value="xls"><a href="#" class="crQuickOutputXLS">Save to Excel File</a></option> </select> </script>
```

I have tried all the variations on this code that I can think of to make this work, but the macro just doesn't seem to be able to find the form. If any one has any ideas that might fix this, I would be very grateful to hear them.

Thanks

Comment: Try without the form tag:  `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:cr_saveToMenu CONTENT=$Save<SP>to<SP>Text<SP>File`  or without the form ID:  `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:* ATTR=ID:cr_saveToMenu CONTENT=$Save<SP>to<SP>Text<SP>File`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use EVENT. Uncheck the ID recording option and record different types of drop downs. Then check which property in EVENT is changing and you can put there {{!LOOP}}.